# How can i convert a BitString into a String in Elixir?

Tags: string, types, erlang, elixir, bitstring

I have a function that receives a list of strings and concatenates each string into a new string, i do that using Enum.join. But when i try this operation, i get the following error:

```
** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol Enumerable not implemented for "int main(){return 2;}" of type BitString. This protocol is implemented for the following type(s): Date.Range, File.Stream, Function, GenEvent.Stream, HashDict, HashSet, IO.Stream, List, Map, MapSet, Range, Stream
```

My way around this was trying to convert the BitString into a String, but i can't find anything for doing this in Elixir's documentation.
My other solution was trying to not get that BitString at all but i don't even know why i'm getting that BitString to begin with.

The process i'm doing is to receive a list like this: `[{"int main(){return 2;}", 1}]`
Then i make a list but only using the string `text=Enum.map(words, fn {string, _} -> string end)`

I tried printing the result so i'm sure i'm giving the correct argument; by using `IO.inspect(text)`, i got `["int main(){return 2;}"]`, which looks like a list of strings to me.

Then i pass that to a function using `Enum.flat_map(text, &lex_raw_tokens(&1, line))`

Inside of that function, i do 
`def lex_raw_tokens(program,line) when program != "" do
       textString=Enum.join(program, " ")`

This is where i get the error. Is there any way of turning that BitString back into a String or not get that BitString?

Sorry, i'm still learning Elixir and honestly so far it's the most dificcult lenguage i've learned and i'm having a lot of troubles with it. Also, this whole thing is part of a small C compiler i'm doing as a school proyect

Comment: Sadly no, that was my own question and i admit i wasn't specific enough so no one could answer it.

Comment: The title is extremely misleading, so I closed it as a duplicate of the previous one.

Comment: [Enumerate a string in Elixir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67791728/enumerate-a-string-in-elixir)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `text` bound to `["int main(){return 2;}"]`, then you're doing an `Enum.flat_map/2` over `text`, so inside `lex_raw_tokens/2`, `program` is bound to `"int main(){return 2;}"`. You're then trying to do an `Enum.join/2` on `program`, but since it's a string (which is a kind of `BitString`), it's not enumerable.

Comment: So ````Enum.flat_map```` passes the string ratter than the list?

Comment: Yes, most of the `Enum` functions pass each item to the provided function. The docs for `Enum.flat_map/2` have some good examples: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#flat_map/2